# Apigee API end point gives 503 on the browser, but a 200 on Apigee trace and curl

Tags: browser, apigee, http-status-code-503

We use Apigee proxy to invoke our API. All works well when we test it out within Apigee trace. Also works fine with curl. But on a browser, it gives a 503. This is not consistent though, sometimes it gives a 200 on the browser too. Tried Chrome and Firefox, same behavior.

Our API still executes well though. We do not return any response, merely set the status. Any ideas on what we could try out to get a 200 on the browser?

Comment: 503 Service Unavailable generally signifies an issue with the server, and has nothing to do with the request sent in or the app/user agent making the request. When you trace the call, and receive the 503, does your call show up in trace? If you can see it, do you have a backend target that is returning the 503?

Comment: is it GET request you are sending from browser while the API is configure only for POST/PUT?

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things to check:

1. Check if your Browser has a DNS entry caching. Sometimes services like ELB changes the actual IPs. So caching DNS entries may result in 503.
2. Another you may want to check is the difference is in the HTTP Verb used. Browsers send a GET request. But curl commands can do all.  So if your service is specifically not serving GET calls you may get some server side errors. Also curl sends certain headers even if you do not explicitly send. E.g., Accept:*/* header and user-agent header etc. Check if the server is behaving differently based on those headers.

Answer (score -2):

You should look into using Chrome or Firefox extensions for this.  There are two in particular which support a wide range of additional features for API developers.

For Chrome, try [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com/).

For Firefox, try [RESTClient](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient/).

Thanks.