# 503 Service Unavailable but heroku logs show 200

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, logging, heroku

I'm making an expensive call to my Heroku Rails server. After 13-15 seconds the console in my browser reports a Service Unavailable 503 error. However when I check my heroku logs, it reports:

```
Completed 200 OK in 45592ms (Views: 220.3ms | ActiveRecord: 33457.5ms)
```

Other times the heroku logs report a memory exceeded quota. Here is an example of that below.

```
2015-06-11T15:17:20.238285+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 81881ms (Views: 201.6ms | ActiveRecord: 18021.2ms)
2015-06-11T15:17:33.482930+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=841M(164.4%)
2015-06-11T15:17:33.482930+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2015-06-11T15:17:53.147570+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=841M(164.4%)
2015-06-11T15:17:53.147679+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R14 (Memory quota exceeded)
2015-06-11T15:17:59.751540+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2015-06-11T15:17:59.695813 #3] ERROR -- : worker=2 PID:13 timeout (121s > 120s), killing
2015-06-11T15:17:59.916750+00:00 app[web.1]: E, [2015-06-11T15:17:59.906435 #3] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 13 SIGKILL (signal 9)> worker=2
2015-06-11T15:18:02.487428+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2015-06-11T15:18:02.427293 #16]  INFO -- : worker=2 ready
```

Why is it reporting a Completed 200 when the console is reporting a 503?

Comment: Are you completely certain that the entry you gave above in the Heroku log corresponds to the request you sent from the browser?

Comment: Yes I am. There is only one request sent and I'm the only one using the app.

Comment: This isn't rails but it has a couple of general things to try to debug this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22386148/apigee-api-end-point-gives-503-on-the-browser-but-a-200-on-apigee-trace-and-cur

Comment: One more question: Does the browser receive anything incoming _after_ the 503 response from Heroku?  Can you test this using a tool like SOAP UI?  I ask this because I am curious whether Heroku is actually attempting to send something back after it completed with the 200 code.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, no. The call is via AJAX and none of the callbacks are fired. The issue with testing it out with tools is that this only comes up when I'm sending LOTS of data.

Answer (score 3):

there are 2 different things here:

- your app
- the heroku load balancer

In this case the load balancer see that the request is taking too long and sends you the 503. In the back the service processes the request and returns completes with a 200.

See:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/limits

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout

Comment: I've set my timeout to 120 seconds. Considering the 503 error appears after 13 seconds, i don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Looking through the logs and searching for H12 i found that after 30 seconds the router times out and returns a 503 message. This is documented in the limits article listed in this answer.

Comment: Voting up, as for me, 30 seconds limit was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku does not gives us much information for `error-code = H10`. Simple put, something is going wrong with your application code / configuration. To see what's going wrong, run `heroku run rails console` and you will be able to see error details which will be help you in resolving the error. No need to use logs. `heroku run rails console` is a big help

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me when I used Node. I put a timeout for 30 seconds and I used to get HTTP:503. I then came to know that it's the timeout that caused the issue. I changed the timeout to <30 seconds and it is working fine. Maybe it's because of the loadbalancer that Heroku uses.
Thanks.